# How can I get invocations per method from a Mockito mock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to get a number of invocations per a given method from a Mockito mock.

Lets say I declared a mock and two stubbing for it:

```
when(mock.methodA()).thenReturn(..);
when(mock.methodB()).thenReturn(..);
```

I can do something like `Mockito.mockingDetails(mock).getInvocations()` but it returns a collection of all invocations. I want to get a number of invocations for the `methodA` only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use verify(), for example:

```
verify(mock, times(N)).methodA();
verify(mock, times(N)).methodB();
```

when **N** check for invocation numbers.

For getting data about specific method only use thats:

```
 new DefaultMockingDetails(service).getInvocations()
                    .stream()
                    .map(InvocationOnMock::getMethod)
                    .filter(s -> s.getName().equals("methodName"))
                    .collect(toList())
```

this method will return Collection invocations for that mock.

for more info see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify)

Comment: Yep, this works fine but unfortunately does not return the number of invocations. In my case I explicitly need to get the number of invocations to build a more complicated assertion.

Comment: I change my answer. That's what you need.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I found `Mockito.mockingDetails(mock).getInvocations()`.  This will still returns a collection of invocation for both methods. The question is how to get invocations only for the `methodA`?

Comment: ok. you can use that         new DefaultMockingDetails(service).getInvocations()
                        .stream()
                        .map(InvocationOnMock::getMethod)
                        .filter(s -> s.getName().equals("methodName"))
                        .count()
        );   ...Or .collect(toList()) I don't see any problem :)

Comment: @fyrkov *"In my case I explicitly need to get the number of invocations to build a more complicated assertion."* **---** I'd rather stick with the assertions provided by `JUnit` and `Mockito`. The reason is that one of the most important properties of UnitTests is that they **fail for the right reason**: the CuT does not meet the expectations. When you build your own "more complicated assertion" chances are that *they* are wrong instead of the CuT...

Answer (score 3):

I think I overlooked that the `Invocation` object has a `getMethod` property inherited from the superclass `InvocationOnMock`. Therefore it is possible to do something like:

```
Mockito.mockingDetails(mock).getInvocations().stream()
                        .map(InvocationOnMock::getMethod)
                        .map(Method::getName)
                        .filter(methodName -> methodName.equals("methodA"))
```

Not super neat but does the job.